# QXmlStreamReader and empty namespaceUri() on attributes

Tags: xml, qt, xml-namespaces, qxmlstreamreader

This is as much an XML question as it is a Qt one: Why does the following test for a namespace-uri of the `attr` attribute of the `foo` element fail?

```
{
    const QString test("<foo xmlns='http://example.org/ns' attr='value'><empty/></foo>");

    QXmlStreamReader r(test);
    QVERIFY(r.namespaceProcessing());
    QVERIFY(r.readNextStartElement());
    QCOMPARE(r.name().toString(), QLatin1String("foo"));
    QCOMPARE(r.namespaceUri().toString(),
             QLatin1String("http://example.org/ns"));
    QVERIFY(!r.attributes().isEmpty());
    QCOMPARE(r.attributes().front().name().toString(),
             QLatin1String("attr"));

    // FAIL, namespaceUri() is empty:
    QCOMPARE(r.attributes().front().namespaceUri().toString(),
             QLatin1String("http://example.org/ns"));
}
```

Is this a `QXmlStreamReader` bug, or are XML attributes in general not in the namespace declared with `xmlns`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML attributes are not in the namespace declared with `xmlns`.

Had the same question and found the answer in the [specification of namespaces in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting):

> A default namespace declaration applies to all unprefixed element names within its scope. Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names; the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear.